# Select value in array Json using jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have one json file.

```
{
"cars": 
[
    { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
    { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
    { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
]
}
```

I need to give one of the models as input and I want the corresponding name of the car will be the output.

Using jq, I wish to achieve. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

With this filter in the file cars.jq:

```
.cars[]
| select(.models|index($model))
| .name
```

and your JSON in cars.json, the invocation:

```
jq --arg model Panda -f cars.jq cars.json
```

yields:

```
"Fiat"
```

Of course there are many other ways in which the model name can be passed in to the jq program.

As a one-liner:

```
jq --arg model Panda '.cars[] | select(.models|index($model)) | .name' cars.json
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

Syntax `jq '.keyName<array/single value>'`

```
cat file.json | jq '.cars[]' // retunts array of cars
cat file.json | jq '.cars[].name' // retunts list of names
cat file.json | jq '.cars[].models[]' // retunts array of car models
```

Comment: the above queries give the whole car names or models. But I need to get the specific car name for the given model inupt

Comment: I don't think JQ is that advance, I normally use bash script to load json to an array and use it as an object to run queries against it.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why you are requesting jq. In plain vanilla Javascript, the solution is very simple. I don't know if this is the most efficient way, but I would recommend a simple, easy to understand plain vanilla solution over anything else. Unless efficiency is an issue and a sufficiently more efficient solution can be found. Here, I've hardcoded the model "Focus" in the function call and this returns the name "Ford".

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function getNameOfModel(model) {
                var nameOfModel = "Unknown";
                var jsonData = {"cars": [
                    { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
                    { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
                    { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
                    ]};
                var jsonArray = jsonData["cars"];
                var i = 0;
                while (i < jsonArray.length) {
                    if (jsonArray[i]["models"].includes(model)) {
                        nameOfModel = jsonArray[i]["name"];
                        i = jsonArray.length;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                document.getElementById("carName").innerHTML = nameOfModel;
            }            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><p id="carName"></p></div>
        <script>getNameOfModel("Focus");</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am writing bash script which uses jq. so trying with jq itself rather than going with Javascript